# Start working with eclipse and Ionic Framework

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently started working with eclipse and I'm using phonegap, ionic framework and cordova.
I'm new in this field so I need some help to work things out. I linked my "index.html" page the ionic css and every thing works fine- the header, buttons etc. But when i try to new stuff like menus and all sort of things I'm stuck.
Also, I heard that there is an easier way to work with ionic framework- some sort of console, but I didn't quite understand.

Can someone help me to proceed? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic has a [website](http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/) with some tutorial videos

Also, they have a [CLI](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli) (command line interface), like Phonegap/Cordova but with some extra features

Answer (score 1):

Try JBoss Tools for eclipse. Great support for angular.